# Time to allow to get through Athens Customs and connect to flight to Santorini

Tags: short-connections, ath

I am currently planning a trip to Greece. I am flying to Athens International Airport but I'd like to go to Santorini. I already have the tickets to Athens but before booking tickets from Athens to Santorini, I'd like to know how long the connection between the flight is going to take.

I don't know if I'll have to go through Customs or anything between the flight.

Additional details :

•first flight will come from the Australia via Dubai arrive Athens 15.30
•second flight will go to Santorini (domestic flight).
•I have only have 1 luggage so bag to take and check-in.

Answer (score 5):

Depending on your airline (AFAIR there are only two flying ATH-JTR):

- Ryanair: plan two hours
- Aegean: 90 minutes should be enough

Passport control in ATH is fast, if you're from a non-visa country Greeks don't seem to ask any questions except "how long you gonna stay". Expect 15-20 minutes max unless you're unlucky. However since you fly with the luggage, this might take a while, and you can take overall up to 40 minutes before you leave the customs. They don't really hurry there.

Now, if you fly Ryanair to Santorini, you'd have to check in your bag. There will be a line, which will be LONG (because Ryanair asks non-EU passengers get a stamp at check-in even for domestic flights), and checkin counter closes 60 minutes before flight (not exactly, but with Ryanair I wouldn't push it). So you better be there at least 80 minutes before the flight.

If you fly Aegean, however, they only close check-in counter 30 minutes or so before the flight, and they're not busy. They also have a separate bag  drop area, and you can check in online (they don't have this retarted Ryanair rule and don't require any stamps). Thus you need much less time.

Security in ATH is fast, and it is max 10 minutes from there to the gate.

PS. Before leaving, **check the Greek news to make sure Greek pilots/airport staff/ATC/whoever else are not planning to strike while you're there**. Seriously. They do strike regularly. I've been there in Oct when they went on strike, and was a complete chaos, with effect lasting long after the strike was canceled.

Comment: @Lee don't forget that (because you are connecting to a flight that's not part ofthe same booking) if you miss your flight to Santorini because of a delay, you will almost certainly lose the ticket. A delay of two hours would be unremarkable, and a delay of four or six hours could easily arise if the plane has mechanical problems. If you're changing planes in Dubai, you might be delayed by 24 hours if you miss your connection there.

Comment: @phong is right, but for this particular case I wouldn't bother much. First, even if you lose it, you can book another flight as they're relatively cheap - even purchased same day ATH-JTR was $80 in Oct. And then if you arrive really late (there are no late flights to Santorini), you always have an option to take a boat next morning. It leaves from Piraeus in the morning (7am and 8am) and takes 4-6 hours depending on a boat. Take a bigger/longer boat if you're seasick. Slow, but great views on the way there.